# Disabling animation when using Navigation Component together with BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

How can I disable/change the fading animation when using [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) together with [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView)?

My code to set them up together (in the activity) is as follows:

```
    private fun setupBottomNavMenu() {
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_navigation_fragment)
        val bottomNavigation = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigation, navController)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add anim default files, you can change animation.

```
res/anim/nav_default_enter_anim.xml
res/anim/nav_default_exit_anim.xml
res/anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim.xml
res/anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim.xml
```

Like a below, disable animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</set>
```

Comment: This answer ist almost correct! For some odd reason, now (Q4/2021) it works, when putting those files into `res/animator` instead of `res/anim`. Don't ask me why.

Comment: Move to res/animator folder is working.